# How to cover ToolBarItem after add a Rectangle with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Text("content")
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                            Button {} label: {
                                Text("item")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: 400, height: 800)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        // push to another view
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I want to add a Rectangle after click button, but the Rectangle is still under the toolbarItem, how to resolve it? I just want the rectangle cover everything else.

I have no idea how do I make it

Comment: How about using `.fullScreenCover`?

Comment: I had tried **. fullScreenCover**, but I don't know how to disabled the animation.@BenzyNeez

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `.fullScreenCover`:

*EDIT* Updated to work without animation using the technique found [here](https://codingwithrashid.com/how-to-disable-fullscreencover-animation-in-ios-swiftui/).

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isCoverShowing = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Text("content")
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                            Button {} label: {
                                Text("item")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                Button("Cover me") {
                    var transaction = Transaction()
                    transaction.disablesAnimations = true
                    withTransaction(transaction) {
                        isCoverShowing = true
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isCoverShowing) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
//                    .frame(width: 400, height: 800)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        var transaction = Transaction()
                        transaction.disablesAnimations = true
                        withTransaction(transaction) {
                            isCoverShowing = false
                        }
                        // push to another view
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I disable the animation of  **.fullScreenCover**

Comment: @jack12354 Answer updated to work without animations.